# $il+M=1+M \implies il =1$ or $il=1+m, m\in M$, hence $I=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If we have $R/M$ is a field and $M,I$ are ideals of $R$ such that $M\subseteq I \subseteq R$.

If we take $i\in I, i\not\in M$ we have $i+M \ne 0+M$. Since $R/M$ is a field, we have that $i+M$ is invertible, so $(i+M)(l+M)=1+M$

So $il+M=1+M$. If $il=1$ we get that $i$ is invertible, so $I=R$, but what if $il=1+m, m\in M$, how do we deduce that $I=R$.

(This is in order to prove that $R/M$ is a field $\implies M$ is maximal, please do not invoke this fact.)

Comment: I think I worked it out just now, see my attempt answer

Answer (score 2):

$(i+M)(l+M)=il+M = 1+M$ means:

$il=1+m$ where $m\in M$. Since $M\subset I$ we have $il\in I$ and $m\in I$. Then $il-m\in I$ which means $1\in I$ and $I=R$.

Comment: It looks good to me, congrats. :d just something to note, if $x + M = y  + M$, it doesn't mean that $x = y$, it just means that $x$, and $y$ lie in the same coset (or, by definition $x - y \in M$).

Comment: @user49685 Indeed on the latter part of your comment. I saw $il+M = 1+M$ to mean either 1) $il=1$, in which case $i$ is invertible in $R$ and so $I=R$, or 2) $il=1+m$ where $m\in M$, in this latter case, we have $il\in I$ and since $M\subset I$ we have that $m\in I$. With $il-m =1$ we have that $il-m \in I \implies 1\in I \implies I=R$

Comment: 1) is just a special case of 2) where you have $m = 0 \in M$, so you can just drop the 1) case, you don't need to consider this case. Cheers, :)

Comment: @user49685 True, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Another way: let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ an ideal of $A$.  If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $A/I$, then there exists an ideal $J$ of $A$ such that $I \subseteq J$ and $$\mathfrak a = J/I := \{ x + I : x \in J\}$$ You can obtain $J$ easily: it consists of all $x \in A$ such that the coset $x+I$ lies in $\mathfrak a$.  Also, if $I \subsetneq J \subsetneq A$, then $0 \subsetneq J/I \subsetneq A/I$ (here by $0$, I mean the zero ideal of $A/I$).

Once you've proved the above, the proof is trivial: a field has no ideals except for $0$ and the whole ring.  So, if $R/M$ is a field, then there cannot be any ideals strictly between $M$ and $R$.